# Reset div to original position

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I click on reset button I want the box to go to its original position at top left. I tried using animate but its not working. I need to have the animate and queue function.

```js
$("#start").click(function() {
  $("div")
    .show("fast").animate({
      left: "+=200"
    }, 5000).queue(function() {
      $(this).addClass("newcolor").dequeue();
    }).animate({
      top: '+=0'
    }, 2000).queue(function() {
      $(this).addClass("newcolor").dequeue();
    }).animate({
      top: '+=100'
    }, 5000).queue(function() {
      $(this).addClass("newcolor").dequeue();
    }).animate({
      left: '-=200'
    }, 5000).queue(function() {
      $(this).addClass("newcolor").dequeue();
    }).animate({
      top: '-=100'
    }, 5000).queue(function() {
      $(this).addClass("newcolor").finish();
    })
});
```

```css
body {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  width: 237px;
  height: 167px;
}

div {
  margin: 7px;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 30px;
  background: green;
  display: none;
}

div.newcolor {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="start">Start</button>
<button id="reset">Reset</button>
<div></div>
```

[My JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1vosy3gr/)

Comment: I placed your code in a snippet where it appears to work absolutely fine. What is the issue you have? Also note that it would make a lot more sense to use CSS keyframes to achieve what you need here.

Comment: Thanks. I was just figuring out how to reset the box to its original position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add a `click` event on reset button and apply `finish()` method to the div:

```js
$("#start").click(function() {
  $("div")
    .show("fast").animate({
      left: "+=200"
    }, 5000).queue(function() {
      $(this).addClass("newcolor").dequeue();
    }).animate({
      top: '+=0'
    }, 2000).queue(function() {
      $(this).addClass("newcolor").dequeue();
    }).animate({
      top: '+=100'
    }, 5000).queue(function() {
      $(this).addClass("newcolor").dequeue();
    }).animate({
      left: '-=200'
    }, 5000).queue(function() {
      $(this).addClass("newcolor").dequeue();
    }).animate({
      top: '-=100'
    }, 5000).queue(function() {
      $(this).addClass("newcolor").finish();
    })
});

$("#reset").click(function () {
  $("div").finish()
});
```

```css
body {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  width: 237px;
  height: 167px;
}

div {
  margin: 7px;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 30px;
  background: green;
  display: none;
}

div.newcolor {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="start">Start</button>
<button id="reset">Reset</button>
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this?

```
$("#reset").click(function(){
        $("div").stop( true, true );
        $("div").animate({
          left: 0,
          top: "30px"
        })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

simply use [finish()](https://api.jquery.com/finish/) to reset any ongoing animation

```js
 $("#reset").click(function(){
  $("div").finish();
 });
 $("#start").click(function () {
            $("div")
                .show("fast")
                .animate({ left: "+=200" }, 5000)
                .queue(function () {
                    $(this).addClass("newcolor").dequeue();
                })
                .animate({ top: '+=0' }, 2000)
                .queue(function () {
                    $(this).addClass("newcolor").dequeue();

                })
                .animate({ top: '+=100' }, 5000)
                .queue(function () {
                    $(this).addClass("newcolor").dequeue();

                })
                .animate({ left: '-=200' }, 5000)
                .queue(function () {
                    $(this).addClass("newcolor").dequeue();

                })
                .animate({ top: '-=100' }, 5000)
                .queue(function () {
                    $(this).addClass("newcolor").finish();

                })
        });
```

```css
 body {
            border: 1px solid blue;
            width: 237px;
            height: 167px;
        }
        div {
            margin: 7px;
            width: 40px;
            height: 40px;
            position: absolute;
            left: 0px;
            top: 30px;
            background: green;
            display: none;
        }

            div.newcolor {
                background: blue;
            }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <button id="start">Start</button>
        <button id="reset">Reset</button>
    <div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

use [stop](https://api.jquery.com/stop/) in jquery to stop the animation.

```
$("#reset").click(function () {
     $("div").stop(true, true).fadeOut().removeAttr('style');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by `.clearQueue()` and `.stop()` and then, apply the initial CSS by `.css()`

```
$('#reset').click(function() {
    $('div')
    .clearQueue()
    .stop()
    .css({
        // Add the required CSS properties
        'left': '0px',
        'top': '30px',
        'background': 'green',
        'display': 'none'
    });
})
```

## [Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p468omyz/1/)